# Change Text to Bold using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is the code i use to mail my customers regarding payment details
it works fine.
But i want to send it in bold letters, please help
If possible i want to mail like image

```
function sendEmails() {

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Emails").activate();

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();

  var templateText = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Template").getRange(1, 1).getValue();


  for (var i = 3;i<=lr;i++){

    var currentEmail = ss.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
    var currentClassTitle = ss.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
    var currentName = ss.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
    var PoNo = ss.getRange(i, 4).getValue();
    var inv = ss.getRange(i, 5).getValue();
    var Tds = ss.getRange(i, 6).getValue();
    var date = ss.getRange(i, 7).getValues();
    var chq = ss.getRange(i, 8).getValue();
    var it = ss.getRange(i, 9).getValue();
    var cg = ss.getRange(i, 10).getValue();
    var sg = ss.getRange(i, 11).getValue();
    var lc = ss.getRange(i, 12).getValue();
    var sd = ss.getRange(i, 13).getValue();


    {
    var messageBody = templateText.replace("{name}",currentName).replace("{title}",currentClassTitle).replace("{Po.No}",PoNo).replace("{inv}",inv).replace("{TDS}",Tds).replace("{Date}",date).replace("{Chq}",chq).replace("{it}",it)
    .replace("{Cg}",cg).replace("{sg}",sg).replace("{lC}",lc).replace("{sd}",sd);
    var subjectLine = "Payment-Details-IIT-Hyderabad-Accounts -Rs: " + currentClassTitle;

    GmailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail,subjectLine,messageBody);
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  }                                    
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this easily by providing a parameter called `htmlBody`. It's all in the documentation for [`GmailApp.sendEmail`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options):

> `htmlBody`    `String`    if set, devices capable of rendering HTML will use it instead of the required body argument; you can add an optional inlineImages field in HTML body if you have inlined images for your email

So change this line

```js
GmailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail,subjectLine,messageBody);
```

To this

```js
const messageBody = "<body><p>This is not bolded <b>This is bolded</b></p></body>";
GmailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail,subjectLine,"This will be ignored", {htmlBody : messageBody});
```

Comment: hi sir thanks. where to include variable 'messageBody' in htmlBody

Comment: The message is a thing, you would need to create itself. Just store it in a string and put it in the parameter htmlBody, changing my answer so it has less confusing variable naming